# Marklogic Encoding Insertion using MLCP

Tags: xml, encoding, marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

I have inserted following XML content with "&#x2019" in the content to the MarkLogic server using XQuery.

**XML content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<A>debtor&#x2019;s</A>
```

**Insert XQuery used**

```
 xdmp:document-load("C:/a.xml",
   <options xmlns="xdmp:document-load">
     <uri>a.xml</uri>
     <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
   </options>)
```

And I am using the following XQuery for exporting the same document.

**Export XQuery used**

```
let $xml := doc("/a.xml")
return
  xdmp:save("c:\export\a.xml", $xml,
    <options xmlns="xdmp:save">
      <output-encoding>ISO-8859-1</output-encoding>
    </options>)
```

And the export output XML looks same as source document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<A>debtor&#x2019;s</A>
```

Similarly I have inserted the source XML using MLCP and if I exported that file, it looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<A>debtor's</A>
```

But my need is to have same output as like source (i.e. it should be "debtor& #x2019;s" instead of "debtor's") though inserted using MLCP.

Are there any options or work-arounds to export as like source document for the documents inserted through MLCP?

I also tried `-content_encoding ISO-8859-1` but I got same answer.

Comment: have you tried changing `-content_encoding` value? [MLCP Command Line Options](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/export#id_67189)

Comment: @MichaelGardner yes I tried this but the result was "debtor?s"   instead of "debtor& #x2019;s"

Comment: That would be good information to include in your original question, along with the specific encoding string you used.

Comment: @MichaelGardner I was tried this -content_encoding
ISO-8859-1 but i got same answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
<A><![CDATA[debtor&#x2019;s]]></A>
```